# How to filter data with square brackets?

Tags: sql, ms-access, pattern-matching

I have a text field in MS Access and it has text like this:

```
bla bla bla [hhh] bla bla bla [kkkd]
blo blo blo blo [ttt] blo blo blo [ppp]
jh asdjahsuz uizasdui  asudz j jksdf
```

I'm trying to search for all records that have '[somthing]' in that field.

```
SELECT pruefhinweis
FROM tb_bauteile
WHERE pruefhinweis  LIKE '%[%]%'
```

but this SQL doesnt work, could you please say me how can I do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT pruefhinweis
FROM tb_bauteile
WHERE pruefhinweis LIKE '*[[a-z]]*';
```

**Or**

```
SELECT b.pruefhinweis
FROM tb_bauteile AS b
WHERE b.pruefhinweis Like '*[[]*]*';
```

Comment: @Kaja Notice that pattern will match any `pruefhinweis` value which includes a `]` whether or not a `[` is present.  That is not what your question asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Matching square brackets in a pattern is not intuitive.  See the help topic *"Using Wildcard Characters in String Comparisons"*:

*You can use the special characters opening bracket ([ ), question mark (?), number sign (#), and asterisk (*) to match themselves directly only if enclosed in brackets. You cannot use the closing bracket ( ]) within a group to match itself, but you can use it outside a group as an individual character.*

Either of these will return what you want with a query run from DAO (eg in an Access session using the query designer).

```
SELECT b.pruefhinweis
FROM tb_bauteile AS b
WHERE b.pruefhinweis Like '*[[]*]*';

SELECT b.pruefhinweis
FROM tb_bauteile AS b
WHERE b.pruefhinweis ALike '%[[]%]%';
```

From ADO, you could use the second query or this one ...

```
SELECT b.pruefhinweis
FROM tb_bauteile AS b
WHERE b.pruefhinweis Like '%[[]%]%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pruefhinweis
FROM tb_bauteile
WHERE pruefhinweis  LIKE '*[*]*'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your query returns text with *